# Assign CPUs to each container

Tags: docker

I went through the DCA exam questions, and I found that the two same questions have different answers. Could anyone tell me which is the correct one and why it is correct?

**A host machine has four CPUs available and two running containers. The sysadmin would like to assign two CPUs to each container. Which of the following commands achieves this?**

1. Set the '--cpuset-cpus' flag of the 'dockerd' process to the value 'even-spread'
2. Set the '--cpu-quota' flag to '1.3' on one container and '2,4' on the other container.
3. Set the '--cpuset-cpus' flag to '.5' on both containers
4. Set the '--cpuset-cpu's flag to '1.3' on one container and '2.4' on the other container.

Answer (score 1):

### Some Explantions:

**`--cpu-quota` :** The --cpu-quota option specifies the number of microseconds that a container has access to CPU resources during a period specified by --cpu-period.

**`--cpuset-cpus` :** If you have more than 1 CPU in your system then you need to use this option to specify to container to use how much CPU from which CPU.

**Example:** If you have 3 CPU and 2 core each, now you need to be very specific that your container need to use which CPU out of 3 and if container is going to use multiple CPU partially. (Read again if you couldn't understand).

### Discussion on options:

1. `dockerd` nothing to do with container CPU usage.
2. `--cpu-quota` specifies number of ms that a container use CPU. That means it does not assign CPU to container.
3. `--cpuset-cpus` does assign the CPU to container but you need to specify in comma/hypen separated CPUs.
4. Here. `--cpuset-cpus` assigning the CPU to containers by specifying to use 1 & 3 CPU for first container and 2 & 4 CPU for second container.

Comment: Nice explanation. But Can you please mention what was the correct answer ? I am still confused between option#1 and option#4

Comment: I was confused because option#4 has used "apostrophe s" in the question which is misleading.

Comment: both values in option 4 are set as decimal values, in the [https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#cpuset-constraint](official documentation), it should be either '-' or ',' which is comma or hyphen.

Comment: @AmadoSaladino yes and it should be `--cpuset-cpus="1,3"` and  `--cpuset-cpus="2,4"` . But a/c to question, you can not use hypen (-) as hypen is used for range and a/c to question you need to assign only two CPUs to each container.